# how to get checkbox value for paticular option using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova, checkbox

In my phone gap android application, i have appended the questions and the respective options which is in check box dynamically in div.There are 5 to 6 questions with 3 to 4 check boxes each.But my problem is i need to get the check box value for particular question and not for full check boxes in the div.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

```
function list(results) {
    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        $("#div").append("<li>" + results.rows.item(i).ques + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        var optiontypearray = new Array();
        var arr = results.rows.item(i).option;
        var optiontypearray = arr.split(" ");

        for (var j = 0; j < optiontypearray.length; j++) {
            $("#div").append("<input  id='chk'  name='ckbox' value='" + optiontypearray[j] + "'  type='checkbox'/>" + optiontypearray[j] + "<br/>");
        }

    }
    $("#button").append("<input type='button' value='" + submitbutton + "' onclick='submitanswer()'/>");
} /** while clicking submit button*/

function submitanswer() {

    $('li').each(function(index) {

        var text = $(this).text();
        alert(text);
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
        if (index == 0) {
            alert("s");
            $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(index, text) {
                alert(text);
                alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
                var a = $(this).val();
                alert(a);

            });
        }
    });
}
/**html*/
 <div id="div"></div>
 <div id="button">
```

Comment: can you provide us with some code or other markup ?

Comment: Code would be good, and maybe a scenario, when do you want these values? on a click event or load etc.

Comment: cant u put question numbers in ids of divs/li's which have the questions  and then scan the checkboxes for that question in that div/li ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your submitanswer function you have a jquery each statement. the elements you are looking for should be

```
$(':checked').each...
```

The second argument is actually the element not 'text'. e.g.

```
$(":checked").each(function(index, el)...
```

To get the 'text' for the element use

```
$(el).html()
```

although you can use $(this).html i find it easier to read and prevent mistakes to use $(el)

if you want to match a question against a response i would recommend attaching a label for each question. Then in your each statement you can use the index to match a label with its corresponding answer e.g.

```
<div class="questions">
 <label for="question-1">Do you like ice-cream?</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="question-1" />

 <label for="question-2">Do you want more?</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="question-2" />
</div>
```

Now you can find the questions and answers in this way..

```
var $questions = $('label'), $answers = $(':checked');

$answers.each(function(index, el) {
 alert($questions.eq(index).html() + ' : ' + $(el).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I assigned the same id for question and their respective option.But i need to get when any one option is clicked i should get checkbox is checked and if not i should get not checked.

Answer (score 2):

```
While I'm not sure about exactly what you want to accomplish, this bit of code worked for me.

<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#mySelect option:selected").length)
    $("#mySelect option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this one to see if a checkbox having some value is checked or not. I do not know if its optimal but it should work: :)

```
function isChecked(chkValue) {
        return $("input[type='checkbox']", '#div').filter(function (index) {
            return ($(this).attr('value') == chkValue);
        }).is(':checked');
    }
```